# Why do I get "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception."?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to start my app I get an error. I think I get the error because I tried to add a video in my app, because before I did this everything worked without an error.
This is the error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM J530F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Target debug_android_application failed: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to 'C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\App Entwickeln\Projekte\trainings_app\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\assets/coffee.mp4', path = 'C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\App Entwickeln\Projekte\trainings_app\assets\coffee.mp4' (OS Error: Zugriff verweigert
, errno = 5)
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\App Entwickeln\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 882

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\App Entwickeln\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `flutter clean` then build again

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a file permissions related issue. Do you get error when you try below code in command line? If you have you need to check permission of the path you gave.

```
copy "C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\App Entwickeln\Projekte\trainings_app\assets\coffee.mp4" "C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\App Entwickeln\Projekte\trainings_app\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\assets/coffee.mp4"
```